# What is Jaunty , karmic , gnome means for ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Sorry for that dumb questions but what is the difference between those terms.

Can anyone recommend nay tutorial / books with only few pages (So that i can read fully) to get an better idea about those terminology

Answer (score 2):

Jaunty and Karmic are code names for Ubuntu 9.04 and 9.10 respectively. [Gnome](http://www.gnome.org/) is the name of a desktop environment that's available on many distributions of Linux and other Unix-like operating systems.

Comment: Desktop environment, not window manager. The window manager is called Metacity.

Comment: so u means there two components of linux kernal + Graphical enviroment

The graphical Env is called Gnome. Am i right. kernel is called uBuntu

Comment: Close.  Ubuntu is a Linux distribution.

Comment: Then what is kernel --is that part of Distribution and Gnome is different than distribution or it includes in it

Comment: Linux really is just the kernel. A distribution consists of a combination of the kernel, a set of utilities (e.g. grep, ls, sh, Bash, etc.) and daemons and configuration files, a desktop environment, and more. Different distributions include or exclude some things in order to be useful for different purposes or users' needs and preferences. Of course, this is just an oversimplification.

Comment: ok , now i get an idea . Kernel in windows language means DOS in windows

Comment: @Mirage: No, Windows has a kernel, too. DOS doesn't exist in Windows any more. The command prompt in Windows is a shell called CMD.EXE which would be analogous to Bash.

Comment: is bash same as shell or they different

Comment: Bash is one type of shell. There are several available for Linux including Bourne (sh), Korn (ksh), Z (zsh), C (csh, tcsh), Dash (dash) and more. Often `sh` is a symlink to another shell. On Ubuntu, it's usually linked to Dash.

Answer (score 1):

There's too much for just a few pages, but here's some resources to get you started:

[linux.about.com glossary](http://linux.about.com/cs/glossaries/a/aglossary.htm)

[xwinman.org](http://xwinman.org/)

[Kernel Newbies glossary](http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelGlossary)

Comment: Is there any onebook
 which starts with unix , thenlinux , then distors  and all windows or dektop interface for ubuntu rather than technical definition of evry term

Comment: Dunno. But there's RUTE. http://rute.2038bug.com/index.html.gz

Comment: Basically i want all in one linux tutorial with no technical commands but only showing what are different parts/components of linux and how it started and how it grows . with no technical commands stuff